# Unsure how to fix "lvalue required" error

Tags: c, lvalue

```
#include<stdio.h> 
main()
{
int x,n,r;
scanf("%d" , & x);
    for (n=2;n<(x/2);n++)
    {
            (x%n=r);              //error is here
            (r=0) ? (print("%d\n is a factor")):(print("%d\n is not a factor"));    
    }

}
```

No sure why im getting the "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you are tying to assign `r` to the result of `x%n`. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: It needs to be the other way around, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign `r` to `x%n` which is invalid. You probably wanted

```
r=x%n;
```

Also, replace

```
(r=0) ? (print("%d\n is a factor")):(print("%d\n is not a factor"));
```

with

```
(r==0) ? (printf("%d\n is a factor",x)):(printf("%d\n is not a factor",x));
```

`=` is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator(`==`).